# Jquery TableSorter not sorting numbers

Tags: jquery, sorting

I am using Jquery table to sort my table but its not doing it for numbers.

My data is like that

```
12,235.25
8,238.45
10,235.25
9,230.23
7,230.17
6,230.17
```

Please help how can I change my code?

Comment: It would help if you showed us your code.

Answer (score 0):

It might be the format of your data. You have a comma as a thousand-separator, which the plugin might not be able to handle by default.

Depending on what plugin you are using, you might be able to write a custom parser for your data:

http://tablesorter.com/docs/example-parsers.html